# Could not SSH to GCE instance, then instance became empty

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I was doing some work on my GCE instance and after trying to save a file I received a message from Python that there is not enough memory. I promptly deleted several files to free some space and shut down the instance.

After booting up the instance again i was not able to SSH: "The key transfer to project metadata is taking an unusually long time..." and it went in a loop trying to reconnect. I figured that it's the memory problem, so I expanded the instance memory from 40 to 100GB, but still could not SSH and received some PORT 22 errors (port is enabled in the Firewall).

Trying to figure out how much memory is in use I created my instance snapshot which showed that 32Gb are used, I deleted it right after that. Googling for some time I found this link: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-ssh-diagnostic-sh and ran the following command in cloud shell
`gcloud compute instances add-metadata [instance_name] --metadata startup-script-url=http://storage.googleapis.com/gce-scripts/gee.sh`

After that I was able to SSH to my instance but it is totally empty, not a single folder inside, however software like Python Jupyter notebook is still installed. To check whether everything was deleted I created another snapshot of the same instance and it still shows 32GB.

Can someone explain what is happening? And if it is possible to restore my instance?